# Loading array into sklearn.linear_model

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm trying to load an array, x,  into a regression (reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()) so that I run the prediction function multiple times.

However, whenever I try to load the array using the following:

```
for i in range(0,15):

    reg.predict(np.array(x[i]))
```

I get a value error Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead.

As this is a multivariate regression, with the array x looking like the following, reshaping the array is not possible.

```
array([[5.53600000e-01, 5.02666280e-02, 4.12000000e+01, 3.04170300e-03,
        2.96966300e-02, 9.51813015e-01, 1.43949843e-01, 5.84400000e+04,
        4.60000000e-02, 1.02944112e-01, 9.80000000e+00, 3.61169102e-01,
        3.53892821e-01, 3.73737374e-01, 3.25972495e-01, 2.29560501e-01],
       [6.87500000e-01, 8.92363030e-02, 4.76000000e+01, 3.55677200e-03,
        2.27086180e-02, 9.63474692e-01, 1.27620108e-01, 4.55930000e+04,
        5.30000000e-02, 1.18176453e-01, 1.46000000e+01, 4.36458333e-01,
        4.27125506e-01, 4.57230143e-01, 3.88632873e-01, 2.63273125e-01]...
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Fix found -

```
for i in range(0,15):

    reg.predict(np.array([x[i]]))
```

Missing square brackets !

Comment: what is the shape of `np.array(x[i])` ? can you post some data and code?

Comment: Apologies, have found a fix, please see main post.  Thanks.